# How to refresh GEF editor view

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a multi page editor , 
In the second page of the editor I have a editor where when I double click a tree node 
a view Part opens and I show the graphical editor in the view part and display the tree xpath for the node clicked.

Now when I go to first page I am hiding the view part but If I again go to second page I want to show the same viewpart with the same content , but I am getting black viewPart 
when I do showView(ViewPart.ID).

also I am getting the contents of the rooTEditPart of the GEF editor and trying to refresh the 
child editPArt but then also the view Part is not showing the content.

Please help!!